# Laravel collection filtering to avoid null records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

is there an inbuilt way to loop through collections and return only the objects that are meeting a specific condition?

like skip all records that has `$user->role === null`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually don't even need the `->filter` method if you're using `Eloquent`. If `role` is a relationship of your `User` model, you can simply call:

```
$users = User::has("role")->get();
```

This will automatically return only Users that have a `role`, or where `$user->role` is not null.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `filter` method to filter the users against your condition

```
$filteredUsers = $users->filter(function ($user, $key) {
    return $user->role != null;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what you wont. See docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-where

```
$result = $collection->where('role', null);
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use `reject, filter` functions to achieve this

`$users = User::all();`

```
$users->each(function($users) {
    $users->roles->reject(function($role) {
        return $role->rule === null;
    });
});
```

Please refer to this to use filter -> http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter

Comment: Also, `collect()->reject(null)` works to reject null items in a collection.

Comment: @JoelMellon Also `collect()->filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `whereNotNull()` method that verifies if the value of the given column is NULL :

```
User::whereNotNull('role')->get();
```

Comment: Just to point out that whereNotNull() is an Eloquent method that works on a Model, it won't work on an existing Collection as the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

For laravel collection, `whereStrict` is perfect for filtering to avoid null records.

Because whereStrict compares value + datatype.

```
$result = $collection->whereStrict('role', null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap everything within `if($row->filter()->isNotEmpty())` this has worked for me in the past

Comment: Middle solution... In my case, I had a plucked collection, so filter() worked to remove null values: `$query->pluck('field')->filter()->toArray()`.